# Problems with browsing pages with AJAX

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Menu on my page "Index.php"

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Snackbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Sales
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Local</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Residence</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Purchases</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Registrations
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item Exibe-Lista" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/ProductRegistration.php');">Products</a></li>        
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/CustomerRegistration.php');">Customers</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/EmployeeRegistration.php');">Employees</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/ManufacturerRegistration.php');">Manufacturer</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/ContactRegistration.php');">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="Load_Page('../D_PHP/SaleStatusRegistration.php');">Sale Status</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>   
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Notes</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Bills
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">To Receive</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">To Pay</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Reports</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Corresponding to the page "Index.php" I have the file "Index.js" with the following function:

```
function Load_Page(fileList)

{
    
    if (fileList) 
        
    {
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: fileList,
            url: fileList,
            success: function (data) {
                
                $("#Content").html(data);
            }
            
        });
        
    }
    
}
```

The AJAX function is called when the user clicks on the buttons on the Register Menu > Customers || Products || Employees || Manufacturer || Contacts || State of Sale. However, when I click on these buttons for the page to be invoked by AJAX, the following error occurs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Load_Page is not defined at
> HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I am not able to find the error since the code is correct, and the function that is called in onclick is also. What would be the cause of this error?

Comment: Please explain in your question how this is associated to PHP other than being contained in a file with a PHP extension, otherwise remove the PHP tag.

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript file with the html page?  It’s hard to tell without the full file. You would have done that with a <script> tag.  Just naming the file index.js doesn’t automatically load that file when you access index.php.

Comment: where is your JS code? Did you put it on index.php?

Comment: Wy Your just not simply use the `href` of your `a` tag. You're making it yourself harder than it needs to be